# Referring to interface versus to an object implemeting it?

Tags: delphi

Given the following declarations:

```
var XML:IXMLDocument;
```

and

```
var XML:TXMLDocument;
```

What's the difference of working with the XML variable from end-user point of view? What's preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is explained in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument):

> When TXMLDocument is created without an Owner, it behaves like an interfaced object. That is, when all references to its interface are released, the TXMLDocument instance is automatically freed. When TXMLDocument is created with an Owner, however, it behaves like any other component, and is freed by its Owner. When you add a TXMLDocument component from the component palette to a form or data module, it is automatically created with an Owner. When the TXMLDocument component is created using the global LoadXMLDocument function (or by a function that the XML Data Binding wizard generates to return the root node of the document), the function creates a TXMLDocument instance without an Owner.

So, if the object is created without an owner, its lifetime is managed by interface reference counting. You should declare your document variable like this:

```
var 
  XMLDocument: IXMLDocument;
```

So long as this variable remains in scope, and is not assigned a new value, the XML document object will be kept alive. Once the variable leaves scope, or is assigned a value, the XML document will be destroyed.

On the other hand, if the object is created with an owner, that owner is responsible for destroying the object. In this mode of operation, it does not strictly matter whether you refer to the object through its interface, or directly to the implementing object. However, I feel that it would be idiomatic to refer to the implementing object, just as you would any other `TComponent` instance.

```
var 
  XMLDocument: TXMLDocument;
```

Which route you choose depends on which lifetime management option you prefer to use at this point in your code. I don't think it's possible to give you much more guidance than that. Both options have their place at one time or another.

Comment: Your answer is nice, but if we replace T(I)XMLDocument with some other combination of an interface and implementor, what would change in it?

Comment: Then the answer would be different, depending on what the other types were. I think I answered the question that you asked.

Comment: So there is no intrinsic difference between them? BTW why does SO automatically save comments midst typing O_o

Comment: Pressing enter in comments finishes the comment. You cannot have new lines in comments.

Comment: *So there is no intrinsic difference between them?* I don't know what you mean.

Comment: To put shortly, if I read everything right, if I work with ISomeInterface directly (`var Foo:ISomeInterface`), I have to take care about interface lifetime and whatnot, while if I work with implementing object (`var Foo:TSomeImplementorOfISOmeInterface`), it depends on how that particular class is written, so there is quite a bit of difference between both approaches.

Comment: It all depends on the design of the implementing object.

Comment: There is no generic answer for your question. What you can use and how will it work **always depends** on how particular class is written. In some cases you don't even have choice between using `var Foo: IFoo` or `var Foo: TFoo`, and you would have to use one or the other (depending on how is `TFoo` written)